# SMS Message getting weird characters

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio

We are sending SMS to confirm cel number, but one of them arrived in a weird format, is like adding a "¿" before each character

The Log on Twillio says it was send as follows:

```
Direction -> Outgoing API
Status -> Delivered
Body -> Haz clic en el link miaguila://validate/7/G34DDR para tu número en Mi Aguila
```

But we got something like

```
¿H¿a¿z¿ ¿c¿l¿i¿c¿ ¿e¿n¿ ¿e¿l¿ ¿l¿i¿n¿k¿ ¿m¿i¿a¿g¿u¿i¿l¿a¿:¿/¿/¿v¿a¿l¿i¿d¿a¿t¿e¿/¿7¿/¿U¿0¿C¿X¿0¿I¿ ¿p¿a¿r¿a¿ ¿t¿u¿ ¿n¿?¿m¿e¿r¿o¿ ¿e¿n¿ M i A g u i l a
```

This is a screenshot of what we got

https://s3.amazonaws.com/maothers/unnamed.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are sending unicode characters to Twilio?